# printing out number of sentences in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so I really cannot see what I am doing wrong here, the number of sentences keeps saying it is 0, however I am trying to count the number of sentences/stops with the text.count('.')

Is there anythingin my code which would make this print out "0"?

Thanks

```
def countSentences(fileName) :
    """This is a function to count the number
    of sentences in a given text file"""
    f = open(fileName, 'r')
    text = f.read()
    text = text.split()
    print("Total sentences : " + str(text.count('.')))

    f.close()
```

in Main() I have

```
print(countSentences('phrases.txt'))
```

which passes in a file with numerous sentences.

Comment: Why are you calling `split()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I was calling split as I didn't know strings could be searched/counted, I thought it needed to be a list to achieve that! I removed split and can see how it works now!

Answer (score 2):

It would appear from your code that the var `text` is an array of strings,  so the count will find no strings that are just `.`

Counting sentences is a pretty tricky thing,  since the `.` can show up in a lot of things that are not sentence terminating.  I would recommend something like nltk or spacy to accomplish this task more effectively.

Comment: correct, I guess a . could show up in things not line terminating, however I would think they would be sentence terminating? So is there no way I could maybe make a count of the amount of periods in the list? I am not familiar with nltk or spacy yet.

Comment: Note to reader that `text` is an array because you used the `text.split()`, which splits the text into "words" (space separated)

Comment: If you just remove the `.split()` it will count the `.`s in the whole text

Comment: @StephenCowley understood, see my comment replying to john Gordon on my original post! I see now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's see.
Correcting your code in order to count '.' it's an easy thing to do. It will go like this:

```
  with open('example_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
      text = str(f.read())
      num_sentences = str(text.count('.'))
      print("Number of sentences found: {}".format(num_sentences))
```

However, as Joshua pointed out, counting '.' is not enough. There are a lot of cases in which a dot can appear as not a sentence boundary. For example, consider abbreviations or even emojis. In order to count sentences, you need a natural language processing library designed for that or at least a more sophisticated approach.

Think of a file called example_file.txt with the following inside:

> Hello this is an example file. I am pleased that you found me. The
>   hour now is 2:00 p.m. Hope you have a great day.

Your code would answer 5, but the correct answer is 4.

The following code shows the error and how it can be done correctly using [spacy](https://spacy.io/).

```
with open('example_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    text = str(f.read())
    num_sentences = str(text.count('.'))
    print("Number of sentences found: {}".format(num_sentences))
    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load('en')
    doc = nlp(text)
    print("Actual number of sentences: {}".format(len(list(doc.sents))))
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

**spaCy** will take care of your problem.

```
import spacy 

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

with open('fileNamepath') as f: 
    doc = nlp(f.read())
sentence_tokens = [[token.text for token in sent] for sent in doc.sents]
print(len(sentence_tokens))
```

`sentence_tokens` creates list of strings iterated over each sentence within `fileName` using the iterator `sents`. You can read more about it [here](https://spacy.io/api/doc#sents)